# Azure AD B2C Authentication with Azure AD Multi-tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured Azure AD multi-tenant autentication by following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=applications

The authentication worked on friday last week, but now its suddenly failing. I tried to re-register the application in Azure AD with new App Id and new App secret that was added in both ends.

Error i'm getting:

Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.
AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Authentication is used with a SPA Web App using React with [react-aad-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal)

Answer (score 25):

Solution: Changed platform configuration from SPA to Web solved it.

Comment: how to change ?

Comment: Check your manifest in your Azure Active Directory Application, and look for replyUrlsWithType. Try change the login callback type from SPA to Web.

Comment: "replyUrlsWithType": [
  {
   "url": "https://<YOURTENANTNAME>.b2clogin.com/<YOURTENANTNAME>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp",
   "type": "Web"
  },

Find it here: tenant > App Registrations > Choose your registered App > Manifest blade on left.

Comment: But changing to web requires the client secret to be passed as well?

Comment: @span 

That seems to be the case. Missing client secret is the error I get after switching from SPA to Web, i.e. AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'