# AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I created a `spa` application owned by my organization only, but there was a problem when I requested code. How can I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Try to change the platform configuration from `SPA` to `Web`. What is the result?

Comment: This likely depends heavily on the type of application architecture you are using (not mentioned in the question). I received this error as well trying to use the AzureADProvider in Next-Auth (v4) for a NextJs app (standard NextJs server config - not custom server) with Azure configuration set to the SPA platform. However when I switched to using `@azure/msal-browser` and `@azure/msal-react` I had to switch my Azure app platform back to SPA for the authentication to succeed.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, you have to add the redirect URL under the **web** (not single page application). After that, you will be able to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) to get the **code**.

[image]

Similar problem，see: [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/proof-key-for-code-exchange-is-required-for-cross-origin-authorization-code-redemption/44529/12) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844516/how-to-enable-cors-in-an-azure-app-registration-when-used-in-an-oauth-authorizat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725134/azure-ad-b2c-authentication-with-azure-ad-multi-tenant).

Comment: Thank you, this and the Fiddler advice (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/270056/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-17.html) which exposed the fact that, regardless of what I had configured in azure for the site registration redirect uri, ms login was sending my redirect setting suffixed with "./.auth/login/aad/callback". Matching that in a "Web" registration profile got it working. Btw, I have a SPA, use MSAL2 and set redirectUri to "location.origin" which works for both local and published.

Comment: When adding the Web platform, do you keep the SPA as well?

Comment: @orenrevenge could you solve that problem?

Comment: @norgie Yes, you _do_ keep both: for `Web` you enter `https://<your app's name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` & for `SPA` you simply enter `https://skywalk.azurewebsites.net` - However, after publishing a default Blazor WASM app, I now do see its `Index` page, but no style is applied. WTF?!

Answer (score 8):

There is a problem with the accepted answer: The question was for **SPA WEB**, but the proposed solution was to change it to **SSR WEB**

**For ssr webs**, the flow used is called **OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow** in which a **code** is sent from microsoft after the success login (302 redirect) and the this code is exchanged for a new access_token (microsoft internal apis).

**For spa webs**, in which sometimes there is no a programmable backend server serving the web files (index.html, js, css) able to receive the code and exchange it for an access_token. The flow used is called **OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow** in which ID tokens or **access tokens are returned directly** from microsoft after the success login (302 redirect). Here the official docs

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

> Note: Implicit grant flow is being deprecated in some IAM platforms

If you are developing a **spa web** with pure react, angular,vue, etc **instead of ssr web** with java, c#, php, etc or hybrids like nuxt, next, etc and you need the **access_token instead the auth code (ssr)** you should follow these steps:

### Step 1

Register your app as [admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory) or a simple user

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade

[image]

### Step 2

add a web platform type SPA with the redirect to your spa

[image]

### Step 3

Check the access token checkbox

[image]

### Step 4

In this step, you should be able to obtain the classic values (google, facebook, microsoft, etc) for this kind of login: clientid, clientsecret, reduirect_uri, tenant, etc

[image]

[image]

### Step 5

At the spa source code layer, change the **response_type=code** to **response_type=token** in your authorize url.

Also in **redirect_uri** set your spa base url but encoded. In this sample is : `http://localhost:9000`

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
```

Note: The previous url has break lines to improve the readability. Join the lines in just one line before use it

### Step 6

The flow will be:

- Enter to your spa web : http://localhost:9000
- If access_token is null or expired (*) in the javascript storage, [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690095/3957754) the user to the authorize url (**step #5**)
- Microsoft secure login will start and if credentials are ok, a new redirect is performed from microsoft page

```
https://localhost:9000/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...
```

- In your javascript get the fragment value, store it, validate it(*), and [clear the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753052/remove-url-parameters-without-refreshing-page) to have only `https://localhost:9000`

### Additional

If everything works, all of your final users will be prompted with something like this at the login step:

[image]

To avoid that, with the admin help, [approve it](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/resolving-need-admin-approval-error/) or follow these [infinite steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/mark-app-as-publisher-verified) to mark your app as verified

### Notes

- The explained flow is so basic. You need to research about the refresh tokens and other complex scenarios
- The implicit grant flow is being deprecated in favor of grant code flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow
- The access_token endpoint in your spa (https://localhost:9000/?access_token=***) could be used from anyone to send you fake tokens.

  - That's why you need to validate the token before save it.
  - Also this apply to validate if token is expired
  - Microsoft don't have the [/introspect endpoint](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/), so to validate the token use https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011197/3957754
- if response_mode is query instead of fragment, the returned url will be like this

```
https://localhost:9000/?access_token=eyJ0eXAiOi...
```

### References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application
- https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type
- https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/24/what-is-the-oauth2-implicit-grant-type
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory
- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/
- [Does Azure Active Directory have an OAuth/OpenID Connect token introspection endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378748/does-azure-active-directory-have-an-oauth-openid-connect-token-introspection-end)

Comment: `The application requested an unsupported mode 'query' when requesting a token`. Removing the `&response_mode=query` part from url seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I am late but I've had the same issue in my React SPA Application and the solutions wasn't to change my app to Web in Portal, it was  solving the actual problem which was there was no proof key in my request. I've solved it by my making helper functions and adding this in url where I send users to authenticate:

```
function buildAuthorizationUrl(codeChallenge) {
    const clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID":
    const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:5173/auth/"); 
    // Change to url you need
    const responseType = "code";
    const scope = encodeURIComponent("openid profile offline_access User.Read");
    const state = encodeURIComponent("my_custom_state");
    return `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=${responseType}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&state=${state}&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=S256`;
    }
async function generateCodeVerifier() {
  const array = new Uint8Array(32);
  crypto.getRandomValues(array);
  return Array.from(array)
    .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
    .join("");
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const data = encoder.encode(codeVerifier);
  const digest = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);

  const base64Url = (arrayBuffer) => {
    const base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
    return base64.replace("+", "-").replace("/", "_").replace(/=+$/, "");
  };

  return base64Url(digest);
}
```

And then when user clicks the button for logging I've added this logic:

```
  const handleClick = async () => {
    const codeVerifier = await generateCodeVerifier();
    const codeChallenge = await generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
    sessionStorage.setItem("code_verifier", codeVerifier);
    const authUrl = buildAuthorizationUrl(codeChallenge);
    window.location.href = authUrl;
  };
```

Of course, if you are not dealing with common tenant, that should also be changed in buildAuthorizationUrl function.

Answer (score 0):

I have created same spa application in my organization and created same redirect uri for SPA, since it is inside organization so i did not have access to change configuration for the existing app. It may not be ideal for some cases. I have solved it by sending PKCE information for auth and token request as described in [OAuth](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce#create-code-challenge) .
First generate `code_verifier` from random string then generate `code_challenge` using `code_verifier`.

You need to Add `code_challenge` in your request for `authorization_code` along with `code_challenge_method:S256` (SHA256).
For token `code_verifier` needs to be sent for token request.
Curl Request sample is given below,

Authorization
`curl --location --request GET 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenat_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=<scope>&response_type=code&response_mode=query&sate=demo&code_challenge=<code_challenge>&code_challenge_method=S256'`

Token

`curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenat_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token --form 'code_verifier=<code_verifier>`