# Firebase Authentication with Microsoft. Error "Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption"

Tags: firebase, azure, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a TypeScript React application and I'm using Firebase Authentication for user sign-in. I've set up Microsoft as an OAuth provider, but I'm encountering an issue during the sign-in process.

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.
```

[image]

```
const handleMicrosoftLogin = (
  e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>,
): void => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const provider = new OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result: UserCredential | null) => {
      if (result != null) {
        // Get the OAuth access token and ID Token
        const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        if (credential != null) {
          const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
          const idToken = credential.idToken;
          console.log(accessToken, idToken);
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error: FirebaseError) => {
      // handle errors here
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

I understand that this error is related to the PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) flow in OAuth 2.0, but my understanding was that Firebase should handle this for me.

I've checked my Azure Active Directory app registration and the configuration seems correct:

- The redirect URI is set to https://.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler. Authorized domains are also added in the Firebase Authentication settings.
- Both "Access tokens" and "ID tokens" are enabled under "Implicit grant and hybrid flows"
- The correct account type (Accounts in any organizational directory) is selected under "Supported account types".
- Application ID and Application secret have been added in the Firebase Authentication sign-in method's provider settings.

I'm using the latest version of the Firebase SDK. I would like to keep my application as a *SPA* and DO NOT want to change my platform configuration from SPA to Web (unless I have misunderstood the docs). I also want to avoid adding helper functions and modifying the URL where I send users to authenticate.

Any ideas on what could be causing this error and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already checked the following related questions but none of them seem to offer a proper solution or explanation of the issue:

- [AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692600/aadsts9002325-proof-key-for-code-exchange-is-required-for-cross-origin-authoriz)
- [AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption - Published on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412080/aadsts9002325-proof-key-for-code-exchange-is-required-for-cross-origin-authoriz)
- [Azure AD B2C Authentication with Azure AD Multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725134/azure-ad-b2c-authentication-with-azure-ad-multi-tenant)
- [What is correct platform for using the PublicClientApplication, Web or SPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66454849/what-is-correct-platform-for-using-the-publicclientapplication-web-or-spa)

### ***Update 1***

I found a similar issue, for Auth0 (https://community.auth0.com/t/proof-key-for-code-exchange-is-required-for-cross-origin-authorization-code-redemption/44529/12) in which the solution was to add the platform as Web instead of a Single-page Application in the Azure Platform configuration, which doesn't make proper sense to me.

[image]

Comment: If you are using SPA authentication, then you have to pass code challenge in the request. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code

Comment: @Rukmini I inspected the traffic with Burp Suite and the code_challenge is not passed from firebase by default. How can I pass it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Firebase does not support PKCE](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5935). To keep going you will have to skip PKCE by not registering an SPA reply URL and enable implicit flow as you've already done.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to some reference on how to do that?